# Under Deck Ceiling Using Barn Steel Roofing Panels

Tags: deck

I priced underdeck ceilings at $12/sq ft installed.  That is just way more than I am willing to pay, and I am just not that fussy, so I am going to do my own under deck ceiling using barn steel roofing panels.

I found several people doing this on youtube.  Here is a sample of one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9WUiPOl9co

The existing deck is 12'x36' and I will be sloping the short side.

Right now, my intention is to:

1. buy 3'x12' 26 gauge roofing panels from a big box store,
2. Screw progressively thicker strips of wood to the joists (to provide slope),
3. Screw the roofing panels to the strips of wood,
4. Use a gutter to catch the water at the lower end.

My questions are:

1. What is the **ideal** minimum slope?  I am asking because I don't just want the minimum slope.  I have plenty of headroom, so I can afford a couple of extra inches, but I don't want to slope more then what has a real advantage.
2. How far apart should the strips of wood be such that the roofing panels will not sag over time?
3. Do you have any other tips?

Comment: My concern is whether this traps moisture and accelerates decay of the deck.

Comment: Trapping moisture is a legitimate concern; it is also a concern for the $12/sqft solution as well.

Comment: Is this retrofitting an existing deck or is the deck yet-to-be-built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slope or pitch of the under panels can be at any degree that will shed the water. If you consider it as similar to a roof than according to Code: "minimum slope is 1/4 inch vertical in 12 units (2% slope)" and ideally :"1/2 vertical in 12 units (4% slope)". This is for metal roofs that have a sealant between their lapped seams. My only suggestion would be to remember to use the same metal fasteners as the roof and get the type with the neoprene washer below the screw head. Also depending on the roofs profile pick-up similar support backing (i.e. wavy board).

Comment: Thanks for the ideal minimum slope.  What is wavy board?  Google did not turn up anything obvious.

Comment: Wavy board is a descriptive name for the wood support strips that are installed under fiberglass or metal roof panels. The most popular are shaped for the serpentine  or Quonset type panels (wavy).

Comment: wavy board:                 http://www.lowes.com/pd_13706-1115-2213D_1z10lso__?productId=3012462&pl=1

Comment: I think he won't want to use wavy board, as he's fastening the roofing to the bottom of the joists, and that could prevent runoff. Also, you'll want to find a way to waterproof around the top of the screw holes where you fasten it to the deck. Otherwise water could get trapped between the washers and the roofing.

Comment: Fastnening in the peaks with neoprene sealed screws the water will drop to the troughs and into the gutter.

Comment: I built mine with about one inch slope per eight feet, but although Seattle has a lot of rainy days, *heavy* rains are rare. I also made hinged mine on the side near the house so that I can get to the top of the ceiling to periodically remove debris before any debris dams form. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132461/what-kind-of-latch-mechanism-should-i-use-for-this-movable-ceiling-under-my-deck

Comment: @Michael potter, since ojait provided an helpful answer consider clicking on the up arrow this tells the system you have been helped and can guide others to this answer.